# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 :

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm new to coding and I would like some help with this problem I have.

[Here is the task I got :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFbSC.png)

The code I wrote :

```
guessed_word = input('Please Guess a Word: ')
number_of_letter = '_ ' * int(guessed_word)
print(number_of_letter)
```

Output of the code :

```
Please Guess a Word: hang
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Liran/OneDrive/Desktop/Hangman2.py", line 13, in <module>
    number_of_letter = '_ ' * int(guessed_word)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hang'
```

What can I fix / How can i proceed ?

Comment: you wrote `int` but probably meant `len`. `int` tries to convert the input to a number.. if you input a letter, that doesn't make sense right

Comment: int() doesn't like letters.

Comment: Oh i see , much appreciated !

Comment: x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
Use this to get integer input.